# How to write log and print to screen at the same time?

Tags: python, logging, runtime

I'm writing a buildscript. I want to log everything that is going on, but I also want to see everything while it is running.
What's the best practice to do this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html?

Comment: As far as I understand it, this just logs to a file, but doesn't print to the screen. Am I missing something?

Comment: It logs to *whatever you set it up to*, you can have multiple handlers for e.g. a file (rotated or otherwise), a stream, ...

Comment: Do you have an example? I tried logging.addHandler, but that seems to not be working.

Comment: The docs have several examples and there are plenty of questions on SO and articles elsewhere covering the topic. If after researching it you still have a specific problem, [edit] to give a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to use **tee** command to save output to file

Just write print statement in python script and pipe content to tee command

Tee command capture std in and print  and write it to file.

e.g. console content will be saved to build.log

Linux
$  your_buildscript.py 2>&1 | tee build.log

Windows

your_buildscript.py  | tee build.log

Refernece:
Linux tee: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html

windows tee: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-7.1